# How to pass arraylist<string> from fragment to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, fragment

I want to pass ArrayList which is array keys from firebase database. This array is inside OneFragment and I want to send the keys to the TwoFragment.
But this gives me error like this :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getStringArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

This my OneFragment code :

```
userRef.child(users.getUid()).child("courses").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listMatkul.clear();
                keys.clear();
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for(DataSnapshot dataHasil : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        final String idCourses = dataHasil.getKey();
                        keys.add(idCourses);

                        Log.e("Yhz",idCourses);
                        mataKuliahRef.child(idCourses).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {
                                MataKuliah matkul = dataSnapshot2.getValue(MataKuliah.class);
                                listMatkul.add(matkul);
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }



                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putStringArrayList("keys", keys);
                    //set Fragmentclass Arguments
                    Fragment fragobj=new TwoFragment();
                    fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.asd, fragobj).commit();

                }else{
                }
            }
```

And I retreive data in TwoFragment like this :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ArrayList<String> obj2 =getArguments().getStringArrayList("keys");

        Log.e("nba",obj2.toString());
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: Looks like attributes bundle in second fragment is `null`. But according to your code the new bundle is created and passed to the fragment. Is there other place where this fragment is called without arguments? I would check the bundle way from the fragment creation to the place where you're using them.